# REST API Design : How to handle a case when a api has to return a list for both equality and non-equality for a field?

Tags: rest, api, api-design

Take for example : 
A case where a an REST endpoint has to list cars which are assigned to a a particular salesman and then show the remaining items which are probably assigned to some other salesmen(Sort by a particular salesman). So it has two sets of data .
1) equal to assignee 
2) notEqual to assignee 
P.S  the List endpoint returns paged responses(Limited by page count)
Can this be achieved by one Endpoint ? Is that even practical ? 
What do REST standards dictate for a scenario like this  ?

Answer (score 0):

> A case where a an REST endpoint has to list cars which are assigned to a a particular salesman and then show the remaining items which are probably assigned to some other salesmen(Sort by a particular salesman). So it has two sets of data . 1) equal to assignee 2) notEqual to assignee

How would you do that for a web site?

You'd probably GET some target-resource, and it would return you an HTML representation with the salesman's cars at the top of the page, and the remaining items at the bottom of the page.

So that's going to be fine.  You would have a different resource for each salesman (the documents generated are semantically different), but your underlying representation might achieve that with a single route that parses the specific salesman out of the URI.

> the List endpoint returns paged responses

That doesn't change very much - each page is a different resource, but again your routing may be able to parse the significant information out of the URI.  If you have default values prepared for any arguments that aren't specific to the resource, then you would be good to go.

For HTML representations, you'd probably include the paging links within the representation.  You also have the option of describing Links in the response headers, for clients that understand that.

Your implementation would need to understand how to compute the spellings of the different URI to use for each of the links you were supporting (first, last, previous, next).

The references below may help

- [RFC 5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988) Web Linking
- [RFC 5005](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005) Feed Paging and Archiving

Comment: I was thinking of the single route way only . In my case i have an experience API which composes response from  a System API . So in this my experience api can do both /cars?assignee="Username" & /cars?assignee="neq_Username" .
But the requirement is for the endpoint to get both eq & neq items , This would be ok if my API sits behind a Database . But in this case i have to get users list and others list and then weave them together . At some point i will run out of users item and one of the call will be wasteful since it will not return anything  after reaching a certain range of pages